Getting a CMB map from the Cls using CAMB
I'm trying to get a temperature anisotropies map using CAMB, and I getting a trouble. In first place, I'm doing this with the following code:
import camb
import healpy as hp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pars = camb.set_params(H0=67.5, ombh2=0.022, omch2=0.122, mnu=0.06, omk=0, tau=0.06,  
                       As=2e-9, ns=0.965, halofit_version='mead', lmax=3000)
nside = 512  
T0 = 2.726 * 1e6 


def cmb_temperature_map(nside, pars):
    
    results = camb.get_results(pars)
    powers =results.get_cmb_power_spectra(pars)
    totCL=powers['total']
    ClTT=totCL[:,0]

    cmb_map_test = hp.synfast(ClTT, nside, new=True)


    alm = hp.sphtfunc.synalm(ClTT)
    map_cmb_anis = hp.sphtfunc.alm2map(alm, nside=nside)
    map_cmb = T0*(np.ones_like(map_cmb_anis)+map_cmb_anis)/1e6 
    
    return map_cmb, cmb_map_test
    

cmb, anis = cmb_temperature_map(nside, pars)

hp.mollview(cmb)
hp.mollview(anis)

I don't see any error, and I think that the simulation of the Cls its ok. But when I plot the maps, I'm getting anisotropies biggers than the expected. Can someone find my problem?
This is my plot in K: the anisotropies are so big.


can you maybe show us the output of the program and explain why you think the anisotropies are too large?

Can someone find my problem? Implementation details of computational tasks are off-topic on this site: “While computational physics is on topic, we are not a programming site. If your question is about implementing computational code - in particular, if it's about writing, compiling, debugging or optimizing code, or about a specific language or library - then it is off topic.”

How much bigger? Is the distribution of hot and cold spots ok statistically if you look at the $a_{\ell m}'s$ directly from the map and the only issue is the overall scale, or does your map have other problems? If it's just the overall scale, did you double and triple check that all of the functions you are using from the code are normalized the way you expect them to be? Are you sure your expectation for how big the fluctuations should be is correct and in the right units to compare with the output of the code?

I have already include the plot in the post!!

Why is there a $1e6$ in T0 = 2.726 * 1e6 ?

to use the temperature in muK
